# Angularjs directive binding update delay

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-digest

I have a problem with directive binding. On the moment when `ng-change` fires in the event handler I have correct value in ng-model prop but the next line is a call to method binded from controller and in controller handler property which is binded to directive have previous value - it updates one moment later. I'm guessing it is because of digest loop execution steps. Is there a way to have same value on directive and on controller at this moment? [Plunker example](http://embed.plnkr.co/SgIxHK9fSni7qYSCkFeu/). One of the solution is to wrap directive event handler code into `setTimeout`. Is there any other, more 'angular' ways to handle this correctly?

My html:

```
<text-box textvalue="vm.userInput" loadvalue="vm.onLoadValue()"></text-box>
```

controller:

```
angular.module("app").controller("mainController", function(){
  var that = this;
  that.onLoadValue = function(){
    console.log(this.userInput);
  }
});
```

directive:

```
angular.module("app").directive("textBox", function(){
  return {
    restriction: "E",
    template: `<input ng-model="textvalue", ng-change="vm.onChange()"/>`,
    scope: {
      textvalue: "=",
      loadvalue: "&"
    },
    controllerAs: "vm",
    controller: function($scope){
      var that = this;
      that.onChange = function(){
        console.log($scope.textvalue);
        $scope.loadvalue();
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing loadvalue method to the directive you can watch variable.
[Working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/VDc2QthXxXepJ4IcEkBB)

```
angular.module("app").controller("mainController", function($scope){
  var that = this;
  that.text="test text";

  $scope.$watch("vm.userInput", function(newValue){
    that.tempValue = newValue;
    console.log(newValue);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide the value as a local in the `loadvalue` expression:

```
angular.module("app").directive("textBox", function(){
  return {
    restriction: "E",
    template: `<input ng-model="textvalue", ng-change="vm.onChange()"/>`,
    scope: {
      textvalue: "=",
      loadvalue: "&"
    },
    controllerAs: "vm",
    controller: function($scope){
      var that = this;
      that.onChange = function(){
        console.log($scope.textvalue);
        ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶l̶o̶a̶d̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶(̶)̶;̶
        $scope.loadvalue({$value: $scope.textvalue});
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Usage:

```
<text-box textvalue="vm.userInput" loadvalue="vm.onLoadValue($value)"></text-box>
```

The `$value` local furnished the Angular expression will be the current value without the delay of a digest cycle.